# mysql inserting with foreign key

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys

i do have a form field which includes values which will be put in different tables in mysql.

they are all connected with foreign keys.

how do i put these values to different tables.

pseudo tables:

```
users_table:
userId|userlogin

user_info:
info_id|userId|name|surname

user_contact:
contact_id|userId|phone|email


form includes:
userlogin
name
surname
phone
email
```

in my research, i found out that i can use `mysql_insert_id` to link the FKs, but i wonder if that can cause problems if there is high load in the website (diff. requests sent at the same time).

i also found out that i can set triggers to create new fk values:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_kimlik AFTER INSERT ON hastalar
for each row
insert into hasta_kimlik set idhasta = new.idhasta
```

but i don't know how to add data to them. i can use
`UPDATE table SET (name, surname) VALUES ('John', 'Brown') WHERE info_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();`

but it doesn't feel the native way.

what is the best practise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i found out that i can use mysql_insert_id to link the FKs, but i wonder if that can cause 
>   problems if there is high load in the website (diff. requests sent at the same time).

mysql_insert_id returns the last auto-increment value generated **by the database connection currently in use**.

It doesn't matter what other processes do on other connections. It is safe. You'll get the right value.

> but it doesn't feel the native way.

nope. The right way is :

- INSERT user
- get id
- INSERT user_info

Comment: one more thing, i wonder the purpose of using a trigger then, is it useful or is there a way to make it useful for this case. maybe for many-to-many relationships but else, i don't know...

Comment: In this particular case the trigger on users doesn't know what you want to insert in the user_info table so it is not useful at all. Better stay simple...

Answer (score 1):

If the tables are connected by foreign keys shouldn't you just start with the basic table (users_table here) and then add in either user_info table and then in user_contact table, or the other way around. As long as you have filled in the table that has the primary key of the fk's in the other tables, then you can add easily.

- **INSERT SQL command:**

> INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1,
>   value2, value3,...)

Is that what you were asking?